# Set a HTML5 Video element to cover?

Tags: javascript, css, html, video

In css, background images can use the size property of cover, this means the image will always be exactly big enough to fill the space.

I want to create this same sizing principal with an HTML5 video element. Does anyone have an example of how to do this?

The trick is figuring out width:height ratio of the box/window you're fillings compared to the video and adjust accordingly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a bit of JQuery, you might want to have a look at this plugin- http://syddev.com/jquery.videoBG/

Also, a great super comprehensive article on using HTML5 video is the Dive into HTML5 series - http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html

Comment: Plugin doesn't react to resize events. I will probably just roll my own version of this.

Answer (score 0):

VideoBG is nice, but works by setting the element to fixed position, so it can be used, for example, for implementing effects where the video is inside a "scrolling page", and so on, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the CSS translate property as it is calculated on element size, it allows you to center it no matter the resolution of the video output you have.

You can keep ratios using min-width and min-height

```
position:absolute;
top: 50%;          
left: 50%;         
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
-moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Rayjax/50t03awj/2/)